# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createDocumentFragment') jquery.mycart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the jquery.mycart.js plugin in my shopping website.
Unfortunately, I got this error and I couldn't know what's the problem.

*Cannot read properties of null (reading 'createDocumentFragment')*
in this line :

````
    $addTocartBtn.prepend($image);```

This is the activating script :
```$(function () {

  var goToCartIcon = function($addTocartBtn){
    var $cartIcon = $(".my-cart-icon");
    var $image = $('<img width="30px" height="30px" src="' + $addTocartBtn.data("image") + '"/>').css({"position": "fixed", "z-index": "999"});
    $addTocartBtn.prepend($image);
    var position = $cartIcon.position();
    $image.animate({
      top: position.top,
      left: position.left
    }, 500 , "linear", function() {
      $image.remove();
    });
  }

  $('.my-cart-btn').myCart({
    classCartIcon: 'my-cart-icon',
    classCartBadge: 'my-cart-badge',
    affixCartIcon: true,
    checkoutCart: function(products) {
      $.each(products, function(){
        console.log(this);
      });
    },
    clickOnAddToCart: function($addTocart){
      goToCartIcon($addTocart);
    },
    getDiscountPrice: function(products) {
      var total = 0;
      $.each(products, function(){
        total += this.quantity * this.price;
      });
      return total * 0.5;
    }
  });

});```

Can you help me please?
````

Comment: Without seeing your code, I would suspect that the element in **$addTocartBtn** cannot be found on the page at the time this code is being ran.

Comment: I have edit my quetion, can you see the code please?

Comment: Here is a simple solution to narrowing down your issues. At the top of **goToCartIcon**  add **console.log($addTocartBtn);** If it doesn't console an element, that means the element doesn't exist that $addTocartBtn is supposed to reference.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Infact, the problem was due to the version of jquery. When I downgrade the jquery version to 2.2.4, it works very fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to the version of jquery. When I downgrade the jquery version to 2.2.4, it works very fine.
The bootstrap version is 4.3.1.